# Dragging from a tableviewcell to a viewcontroller not auto segueing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, segue

I am trying to use Storyboards on this project. I cntrl drag from a static tableview cell to a new viewcontroller select push.

When I run the app and click the tableviewcell, which I dragged from in the previous step, nothing happens?

I am not sure if I have screwed things up by also putting in my tableviewcontroller class the following method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
    }

    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamRounded-Light" size:18]];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamRounded-Light" size:12]];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor statOffWhite];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Profile";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Support";
    } 
    else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Share";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"About";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 4){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"";
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 200);
        UIImageView *watermark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"watermark.png"]];
        watermark.frame = CGRectMake((cell.frame.size.width/2) - (watermark.image.size.width/2), 80, watermark.image.size.width, watermark.image.size.height );
        [cell addSubview:watermark];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

// UPDATE ////////

I took out the cellForRowAt method and the storyboard thing worked. But since I have taken out that method how can I set my font on my cell to be a custom font that isn't in Xcode's selections?  I have included the font in my project, which I use everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What happen with your implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is that your are creating cells from scratch and overwriting the storyboard's cells (hence your segue not being triggered).

If you defined static cells in your storyboard, you should not dequeue and create cells yourself. If your class is a subclass of `UITableViewCellController`, you could call the implementation of `super` and use the returned cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Customize your cell here
}
```

**Note however that doing so makes little sense** : all the things you are doing in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method could and should for simplicity sake be done in the storyboard.

If you really need to customize a static cell programmatically, the way to go is to define an outlet to this cell in your view controller and customize the cell in the appropriate method (`viewDidLoad` for example).